# Warnings when perform cross tabulation using with()?

Tags: r, crosstab, tapply

I am trying to perform cross tabulation in R and calculate the means.

Firstly I selected variables and created a new data frame:

```
      seed <- ruk_trial$Ruk_seed_input   #integer   
      soilec <- ruk_trial$Ruk_soilEC     #num
      ruk_trial$code_smoo[ruk_trial$code_smoo == 0] <- 'US'
      ruk_trial$code_smoo[ruk_trial$code_smoo == 1] <- 'LS'
      ruk_trial$code_smoo[ruk_trial$code_smoo == 2] <- 'HS'
      zones <- ruk_trial$code_smoo       #chr
      netincome <- ruk_trial$NetIncome   #num
      yield <- ruk_trial$Dry_yield       #num
      ruk_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(seed,soilec,zones,netincome,yield))
```

Then I use with():

```
      with(ruk_df, tapply(netincome, list(zones=zones, seed=seed), mean))
```

But it turns out:

```
        seed
  zones 105 120 75 90
     HS  NA  NA NA NA
     LS  NA  NA NA NA
     US  NA  NA NA NA
  There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

  > warnings()
 Warning messages:
 1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

If I use the original dataset, it works:

```
 > cross.tab<- with(ruk_trial, tapply(netincome, list(zones=zones,seed=seed), mean))
```

Can anyone tell me what causes the warnings?

Comment: your `cbind` is making everything into a characters

Comment: `cbind` returns a matrix and a matrix can have only one data mode, so your numeric data is getting coerced to character, and then as.data.frame is converting those character columns to factor. Instead, just do `as.data.frame(...)` instead of `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`.

Comment: Also, for calculating counts, means, and other statistics by group, you might find the `dplyr` or `data.table` packages more convenient. For example, in `dplyr`, to summarise by group (using the build-in `mtcars` data frame): `library(dplyr);  mtcars %>%  group_by(am, vs) %>% summarise_all(funs(n(), mean(.)))`.

Comment: Great thanks! I think using `as.data.frame` to make a data frame is just wrong. It returns `Error in !optional : invalid argument type`. For `dplyr`, could you provide a link or a detailed example here? @eipi10 @Richard Telford

Comment: Sorry, meant `data.frame(...)` rather than `as.data.frame(...)`. For dplyr, see [the vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  ruk_df <- data.frame(seed,soilec,zones,netincome,yield, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I just realised using `as.data.frame` to make a data frame is simply wrong. And `cbind` had converted all variables into factors. @renato vitolo

Comment: The conversion to `character` by `cbind` and then to `factor` by `as.data.frame` was explained by Richard and eipi10.